# Casting a short from a char array

Tags: c, casting

I've run into a small issue here. I have an unsigned char array, and I am trying to access bytes 2-3 (`0xFF` and `0xFF`) and get their value as a short.

Code:

```
 unsigned char Temp[512] = {0x00,0xFF,0xFF,0x00};
 short val = (short)*((unsigned char*)Temp+1)
```

While I would expect val to contain `0xFFFF` it actually contains `0x00FF`. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no guarantee that you can access a `short` when the data is improperly aligned.

On some machines, especially RISC machines, you'd get a bus error and core dump for misaligned access.  On other machines, the misaligned access would involve a trap into the kernel to fix up the error — which is only a little quicker than the core dump.

To get the result reliably, you'd be best off doing shifting and or:

```
val = *(Temp+1) << 8 | *(Temp+2);
```

or:

```
val = *(Temp+2) << 8 | *(Temp+1);
```

Note that this explicitly offers big-endian (first option) or little-endian (second) interpretation of the data.

Also note the careful use of `<<` and `|`; if you use `+` instead of `|`, you have to parenthesize the shift expression or use multiplication instead of shift:

```
val = (*(Temp+1) << 8) + *(Temp+2);
val = *(Temp+1) * 256 + *(Temp+2);
```

Be logical and use either logic or arithmetic and not a mixture.

Answer (score 6):

Well you're dereferencing a `unsigned char*` when you should be derefencing a `short*`

I think this should work:

```
 short val = *((short*)(Temp+1))
```

Comment: That will work on machines (like Intel) that allow misaligned access.  On machines that don't allow misaligned access (most RISC chips), that can lead to problems.  You're correct that the original code was accessing only 8 bits instead of 16.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is that you are only accessing one byte of the array:

- `*((unsigned char*)Temp+1)` will dereference the pointer `Temp+1` giving you `0xFF`
- `(short)*((unsigned char*)Temp+1)` will cast the result of the dereference to `short`. Casting `unsigned char` `0xFF` to short obviously gives you `0x00FF`

So what you are trying to do is `*((short*)(Temp+1))`

It should however be noted that what you are doing is a horrible hack. First of all when you have different `chars` the result will obviously depend on the endianess of the machine.

Second there is no guarantee that the accessed data is correctly aligned to be accessed as a short.

So it might be a better idea to do something like `short val= *(Temp+1)<<8 | *(Temp+2)` or `short val= *(Temp+2)<<8 | *(Temp+1)` depending on the endianess of your architecture

Answer (score 1):

I do not recommend this approach because it is architecture-specific.

Consider the following definition of `Temp`:

```
unsigned char Temp[512] = {0x00,0xFF,0x88,0x00};
```

Depending on the endianness of the system, you will get different results casting `Temp + 1` to a `short *`;  on a little endian system, the result would be the value `0x88FF`, but on a Big endian system, the result would be `0xFF88`.

Also, I believe that this is an undefined cast because of issues with alignment.

What you could use is:

```
short val = (((short)Temp[1]) << 8) | Temp[2];
```